# Line bundles interpretation of modular forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, modular-forms

Let $M$ be a compactified moduli stack of elliptic curves which is considered as a stack over a field $L$. Then modular forms (which are homolorphic at the cusp) of weight $2k$ are nothing but sections of the $k$-th power of the Hodge bundle which comes from the universal family.
I have two questions.

1. is there any good intuition or a modular interpretation of sections of $\Omega^{1}_{M/L}$?
2. If $L$ is a finite field or, more generally, a field of positive characteristic. Is it still a reasonable thing to consider sections of the Hodge bundle and think about them as of "modular forms in char. p"? Especially it is interesting if the characteristic is $2$ or $3$.

Comment: When forms have weight $2k$, please don't call the field $k$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh, yes. That was terrible of me, fixed now, thanks!

Comment: The first 14 pages of this Arizona Winter School document discusses and more from scratch in great detail: https://swc-math.github.io/aws/2013/2013CalegariLectureNotes.pdf